# Communication between TOwnedCollection and Owner Class in Delphi

Tags: delphi, components

I have my own component (TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups) with a TOwnedCollection as a property (TagList).

Every time I add items to TagList the same item should be added to another object (FMenu). This is performed by the procedure `RefreshMenu` called from  `TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.Loaded` on design time.

My issue is I cannot add items on runtime, because `TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.Loaded` is not called.

I thought one solution would be `Postmessage` but I didn't manage to make it work.

The following is the source:

```
  TNiftyListTag = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    FTagValue: string;
    FDisplayTextTag: string;
  public
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property DisplayTag: string read FDisplayTextTag write FDisplayTextTag;
    property Value: string read FTagValue write FTagValue;
  end;

  TNiftyListTags = class(TOwnedCollection)
  protected
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): TNiftyListTag;
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: TNiftyListTag);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TPersistent; ItemClass: TCollectionItemClass);
    function Add: TNiftyListTag;
  end;

  TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups = class(TRVEditFrame)
  private
    FMenu: TAdvSmoothListBox;
    FMenuList: TStringList;
    FCollectionTags: TNiftyListTags;
    procedure SetCollectionTags(const Value: TNiftyListTags);
    procedure RefreshMenu;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure Loaded; override;
  published
    property TagList: TNiftyListTags read FCollectionTags write SetCollectionTags;
  end;

implementation


constructor TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FMenuList := TStringList.Create;
  FCollectionTags := TNiftyListTags.Create(Self, TNiftyListTag);
end;

procedure TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.SetCollectionTags(const Value: TNiftyListTags);
begin
  FCollectionTags.Assign(Value);
end;

procedure TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.RefreshMenu;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
    FMenu.Items.Clear;
    for i := 0 to FCollectionTags.Count - 1 do
    begin
      FMenu.Items.Add;
      FMenu.Items.Items[i].Caption := FCollectionTags.Items[i].FDisplayTextTag;
    end;
end;

procedure TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.Loaded;
begin
  inherited Loaded;
  if Assigned(FRVEditor) then
  begin
    RefreshMenu;
  end;
end;


{ TNiftyListTag }

procedure TNiftyListTag.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
begin
  if Source is TNiftyListTag then
  begin
    FTagValue := TNiftyListTag(Source).FTagValue;
    FDisplayTextTag := TNiftyListTag(Source).FDisplayTextTag;
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;

{ TNiftyListTags }

function TNiftyListTags.Add: TNiftyListTag;
begin
  Result := TNiftyListTag(inherited Add);
end;

constructor TNiftyListTags.Create(AOwner: TPersistent; ItemClass: TCollectionItemClass);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner, ItemClass);
end;

procedure TNiftyListTags.SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: TNiftyListTag);
begin
  inherited SetItem(index, Value);
end;

function TNiftyListTags.GetItem(Index: Integer): TNiftyListTag;
begin
  Result := TNiftyListTag(inherited GetItem(Index));
end;
```

**EDIT**

After Deltics' advice I have amended my code:

```
    TNiftyListTag = class(TCollectionItem)
      private
        FTagValue: string;
        FDisplayTextTag: string;
      public
        procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
      published
        property DisplayTag: string read FDisplayTextTag write FDisplayTextTag;
        property Value: string read FTagValue write FTagValue;
      end;

      TNiftyListTags = class(TOwnedCollection)
      private
        fOnChanged: TNotifyEvent;
        procedure DoOnChanged;
      protected
        function GetItem(Index: Integer): TNiftyListTag;
        procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: TNiftyListTag);
      public
        constructor Create(AOwner: TPersistent; ItemClass: TCollectionItemClass);
        function Add: TNiftyListTag;
        procedure AppendItem(const aDisplayText, aTag: string);
      end;

      TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups = class(TRVEditFrame)
      private
        FMenu: TAdvSmoothListBox;
        FMenuList: TStringList;
        FCollectionTags: TNiftyListTags;
        procedure RefreshMenu;
        procedure SetCollectionTags(const Value: TNiftyListTags);
      public
        { Public declarations }
        constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
        destructor Destroy; override;
        procedure Loaded; override;
      published
        property TagList: TNiftyListTags read FCollectionTags write SetCollectionTags;
      end;

    implementation


    constructor TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
    begin
      inherited Create(AOwner);
      FMenuList := TStringList.Create;
      FCollectionTags := TNiftyListTags.Create(Self, TNiftyListTag);
      FCollectionTags.fOnChanged := RefreshMenu;
    end;

    destructor TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.Destroy;
    begin
      FreeAndNil(FMenuList);
      FCollectionTags.Free;
      inherited;
    end;

    procedure TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.RefreshMenu;
    var
      i: Integer;
    begin
        FMenu.Items.Clear;
        for i := 0 to FCollectionTags.Count - 1 do
        begin
          FMenu.Items.Add;
          FMenu.Items.Items[i].Caption := FCollectionTags.Items[i].FDisplayTextTag;
        end;
    end;

    procedure TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.Loaded;
    begin
      inherited Loaded;
      RefreshMenu(Self);
    end;

    procedure TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.RefreshMenu;
    var
      i: Integer;
    begin
      if Assigned(FRVEditor) then
      begin
        (FRVEditor as TCustomRichViewEdit).OnRVMouseUp := OnMouseUp;
        FMenu.Parent := FRVEditor;
        fmenu.Items.Clear;
        for i := 0 to FCollectionTags.Count - 1 do
        begin
          FMenu.Items.Add;
          FMenu.Items.Items[i].Caption := FCollectionTags.Items[i].FDisplayTextTag;
        end;
      end;
    end;

   procedure TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.SetCollectionTags(const Value: TNiftyListTags);
begin
  FCollectionTags.Assign(Value);
end;


    { TNiftyListTag }

    procedure TNiftyListTag.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
    begin
      if Source is TNiftyListTag then
      begin
        FTagValue := TNiftyListTag(Source).FTagValue;
        FDisplayTextTag := TNiftyListTag(Source).FDisplayTextTag;
      end
      else
        inherited;
    end;

    { TNiftyListTags }

    function TNiftyListTags.Add: TNiftyListTag;
    begin
      Result := TNiftyListTag(inherited Add);
    end;

    procedure TNiftyListTags.AppendItem(const aDisplayText, aTag: string);
    var
      a: TNiftyListTag;
    begin
      a := TNiftyListTag(inherited Add);
      a.FTagValue := aTag;
      a.FDisplayTextTag := aDisplayText;
      DoOnChanged;
    end;

    constructor TNiftyListTags.Create(AOwner: TPersistent; ItemClass: TCollectionItemClass);
    begin
      inherited Create(AOwner, ItemClass);
    end;

    procedure TNiftyListTags.DoOnChanged;
    begin
      if Assigned(fOnChanged) then
        fOnChanged(self);
    end;

    procedure TNiftyListTags.SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: TNiftyListTag);
    begin
      inherited SetItem(index, Value);
    end;

    function TNiftyListTags.GetItem(Index: Integer): TNiftyListTag;
    begin
      Result := TNiftyListTag(inherited GetItem(Index));
    end;

    procedure TNiftyListTags.SetItem(Index: Integer; Value: TNiftyListTag);
    begin
      inherited SetItem(index, Value);
      DoOnChanged;
    end;

end.
```

Items can be added at run time in the following way:

```
var
  a:TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups;
begin
  a:=TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.Create(self);
.....
  a.TagList.AppendItem('a','b');
  a.TagList.AppendItem('c','d');
end
```

Comment: What happens if you call your function on Create?

Comment: On a side note, where's your destructor?

Comment: What's preventing you from calling `Loaded` or `RefreshMenu` whenever you need to? Call or in the `Add` method, for example. I don't understand the difficulty you're facing in this question.

Comment: @RobKennedy I tried this approach first but it didn't work as I was doing something wrong with the code. The second Deltics' idea sounds neater to me tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **TNiftyListTags** is owned by the **TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups**.

Your only 'problem' is that the **TOwnedCollection** class does not provide a typed reference to the owner, by which to invoke the necessary method(s) to refresh the owner when the collection changes.

There are a number of ways to achieve what you want.  However, before presenting options, whatever you do I suggest you do not call **Loaded** to achieve your update/refresh since this method has specific meaning.  Whilst your code in the overridden method may be safe in this context, the inherited implementation may not be.

I would suggest moving the `if Assigned(fRVEditor)` pre-condition check to **RefreshMenu** itself.  **Loaded** then simply calls **RefreshMenu** as may any other code that may need to also call **RefreshMenu**, with the necessary pre-condition checked by the method itself.

Now, as for how and when to call the **RefreshMenu** method, one simple mechanism is to directly invoke the refresh method whenever the content of the collection changes.  e.g. in the **Add** method of the collection.  Since you are using a **TOwnedCollection** as the base class, you could simply type-cast the **Owner**:

```
function TNiftyListTags.Add: TNiftyListTag;
begin
  Result := TNiftyListTag(inherited Add);

  TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups(Owner).RefreshMenu;
end;
```

However, this couples your collection class directly to the specific component acting as the owner.  If your collection is specialised to this class specifically then this may be valid, but it is still undesirable.

To de-couple the collection from the component you could alternatively introduce an **OnChange** event on the collection.  A simple **TNotifyEvent** will usually suffice.

Whichever component then owns the collection may then install a handler for this event.  Whenever the collection changes, invoke the **OnChange** handler.  In this case the **TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups** component will respond to those changes by calling its own **RefreshMenu** method.

```
procedure TNiftyListTags.DoOnChanged;
begin
  if Assigned(fOnChanged) then
    fOnChanged(self);
end;


function TNiftyListTags.Add: TNiftyListTag;
begin
  Result := TNiftyListTag(inherited Add);
  DoOnChanged;
end;


procedure TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.OnTagsChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RefreshMenu;
end;
```

This is typically the approach I adopt and I make the **OnChange** event a private implementation detail, with the handler specified in the constructor by the component instantiating the collection.  This prevents anyone from inadvertently replacing the event handler via any public property etc.

```
constructor TNiftyRVFrameWithPopups.Create(Owner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(self);

  fTags := TNiftyListTags.Create(self, OnTagsChanged);
  ..
end;
```

To facilitate this you obviously need a custom constructor to accept the event handler:

```
TNiftyListTags = class(TOwnedCollection)
..
private
  fOnChanged: TNotifyEvent;
public
  constructor Create(aOwner: TPersistent; aOnChange: TNotifyEvent); reintroduce;
..
end;


constructor TNiftyListTags.Create(aOwner: TPersistent;
                                  aOnChange: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  inherited Create(aOwner, TNiftyListTag);

  fOnChange := aOnChange;
end;
```

Note that the inherited constructor also accepts two parameters, the second being the class of the collection items.  Sine you are introducing a custom constructor you can remove this from the parameters of your own constructor and simply specify the item class in the inherited **Create** call.

NOTE: This does not increase the coupling between the collection and the item class - they are already tightly coupled, by definition (and design).

Comment: fTags := TNiftyListTags.Create(self, OnTagsChanged); doesn't compile for me. E2035 not enough actual parameters.
I tried fTags  := TNiftyListTags.Create(Self, TNiftyListTag); but in this case RefreshMenu is not triggered

Comment: There's a few examples of how the collections can be used in VCL. I don't see any benefit of decoupling the code here because it's owned collection where I think the owner should be *known*.

Comment: @TLama - yes TCollection has a Notify method but this does not contribute anything to enabling notifications with the *owner* of the collection (other than to provide a single point at which to invoke an introduced OnChanged event).  As I said, decoupling isn't strictly necessary here, but it doesn't hurt either and good design is a good habit.

Comment: @pio pio, the code in the answer is not complete.  You are expected to do a bit of work to join the dots.  In this case, to be able to specify a TNotifyEvent in the constructor you must of course implement a custom constructor, taking the change event handler as an additional parameter (the collection item class need not be specified since the collection item class is by definition coupled to the collection class and so can be embedded within your collection constructor).  Your constructor then calls the appropriate inherited Create constructor before assigning the OnChange handler.

Comment: @pio pio - I've updated the answer with an example custom constructor which hopefully will help you further.